# Qt Assistant multilingual

Tags: c++, qt, localization

We are using the Qt Assistant as a new help file system. But since we have an international customer base, we would like to start the Qt Assistant in different languages.

Starting the Assistant with the generated QHC file is not an issue at at all as you can see in the code piece below.

```
   QProcess a_process;
   QStringList a_args;
   a_args << "-collectionFile";
   a_args << S_HELPFILE_PATH;
   a_args << "-enableRemoteControl";
   QFile a_assistantExe( S_ASSISTANT_PATH );
   if ( a_assistantExe.exists() )
   {
      a_process.start( S_ASSISTANT_PATH, a_args );
      if ( !a_process.waitForStarted() )
         return;
   }
```

But how can we start Qt Assistant in a different language? Even after a long search in the internet I didn't found a way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect the source code of Qt Assistant (`main.cpp`) you will find that it will always use the system locale:

```
void setupTranslations()
{
    TRACE_OBJ
    const QString& locale = QLocale::system().name();
    const QString &resourceDir
        = QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath);
    setupTranslation(QLatin1String("assistant_") + locale, resourceDir);
    setupTranslation(QLatin1String("qt_") + locale, resourceDir);
    setupTranslation(QLatin1String("qt_help_") + locale, resourceDir);
}
```

To override the system locale just set the `lang` environment variable before launching your process:

```
if ( a_assistantExe.exists() )
{
   QProcessEnvironment env;
   env.insert("lang", "de"); // replace with your current locale
   a_process.setProcessEnvironment(env);
   a_process.start( S_ASSISTANT_PATH, a_args );
   if ( !a_process.waitForStarted() )
      return;
}
```

It will not only change the language of Qt Assistant itself but also will use the corresponding translated versions from your .qhc file (`<file language="de"></file>`, `<text language="de"></text>`, ...)

Comment: Glad to help! It was actually very interesting.